# clickable string array items inside each recycleview item

Tags: java, android

I have an API which have data like this:

```
{"seasons":[
{
"id":"1",
"titles":"1title1;1title2;1title3",
"url":"1url1;1url2;1url3;"
},
{
"id":"2",
"titles":"2title1;2title2;2title3",
"url":"2url1;2url2;2url3;"
}
]}
```

I parse it well and in parcelable class I did this for titles:

```
public String getTitles() {
        return titles;
    }

    public StringBuilder getFullTitles() {

        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        String[] titlesArray = getTitles().split(";");
        for (String title : titlesArray) {
            builder.append(title + "\n");
        }
```

and this for url:

```
public String getUrlAdaptive() {
        return urladaptive;
    }

    public StringBuilder getFullUrlAdaptiveFinal() {

        StringBuilder builder2 = new StringBuilder();
        String[] urlArray = getUrlAdaptive().split(";");
        for (String details : urlArray) {
            builder2.append(details + "\n");
        }
        return builder2;
    }
```

so in my recycleview adapter I fetch titles data like this in textview:

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.title.setText(String.valueOf(mMoviesItems.get(position).getFullTitles()));    
    }
```

and the result that I got in my recycleview app is like this:

```
1title1
1title2
1title3
2title1
2title2
2title3
```

now you can see that this group:

```
1title1
1title2
1title3
```

refer to the first item of recycleview
and this group:

```
2title1
2title2
2title3
```

refer to the second item of recycleview

you can compare it with api to understand what I mean

what I need to do is to make each item of each group is applicable to be clicked

like when I click on **1title1** I got the url that correspond the title which is **1url1** to open it in youtube
and when I click on **1title2** I got the url that correspond the title which is **1url2** to open it in youtube
and when I click on **2title2** I got the url that correspond the title which is **2url2** to open it in youtube

and so on

it's like click items inside each of main item of recycleview

this is the code after try an answer:

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        holder.title.setText(String.valueOf(mMoviesItems.get(position).getFullTitles()));

        holder.title.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View vview) {
                // here when click on each title I need to get the getFullUrlAdaptiveFinal with it to play it
            }
        });

    }
```

and this is full code for series_list_item.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#21293B"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:visibility="visible" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/url"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:visibility="visible" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Adapter Code:

```
public class SeriesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SeriesAdapter.RecyclerViewHolder> {

        ArrayList<SeriesItem> mMoviesItems;
        private Context context;
        private SeriesAdapterOnClickHandler mClickHandler;

public interface SeriesAdapterOnClickHandler {
    void onClick(SeriesItem movie);
}

    public SeriesAdapter(SeriesAdapterOnClickHandler clickHandler) {
        mClickHandler = clickHandler;
    }

    public void setClickListener(SeriesAdapterOnClickHandler callback) {
        mClickHandler = callback;
    }

class RecyclerViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    public final TextView SeriesSeasontitle;
    public final TextView urlAdaptive;

    public RecyclerViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        SeriesSeasontitle = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        urlAdaptive = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.url);
        view.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int adapterPosition = getAdapterPosition();
        SeriesItem movie = mMoviesItems.get(adapterPosition);
        String text = "already Added To Favorites";
                Toast.makeText(context, text, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        mClickHandler.onClick(movie);
    }

}

    @Override
    public RecyclerViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
        context = viewGroup.getContext();
        int layoutIdForListItem = R.layout.series_list_item;
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        boolean shouldAttachToParentImmediately = false;

        View view = inflater.inflate(layoutIdForListItem, viewGroup, shouldAttachToParentImmediately);

        RecyclerViewHolder holder = new RecyclerViewHolder(view);

        return new RecyclerViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        holder.SeriesSeasontitle.setText(String.valueOf(mMoviesItems.get(position).getFullTitles()));

        holder.SeriesSeasontitle.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View vview) {
                String text = "text";
                Toast.makeText(context, text, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        if (null == mMoviesItems)
            return 0;
        else {
            return mMoviesItems.size();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if (null == mMoviesItems)
            return 0;
        else {
            return mMoviesItems.size();
        }
    }

    public void setMovieData(ArrayList<SeriesItem> movieData) {
        mMoviesItems = movieData;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Activity code:

```
SeriesDetail extends AppCompatActivity implements
        SeriesAdapter.SeriesAdapterOnClickHandler {

    SeriesAdapter mAdapterTrailer;
    RecyclerViewAdapterOthers mAdapterOthers;

    @BindView(R.id.rv_videos)
    RecyclerView mVideosList;

    @BindView(R.id.tv_error_message_display3)
    TextView mErrorMessageDisplay3;

    @BindView(R.id.rv_videos2)
    RecyclerView mTrailersList;
    @BindView(R.id.pb_loading_indicator_trailers2)
    ProgressBar mLoadingIndicatorTrailers2;

    String sortOrder2="seasons/1435";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_series_detail);

        ButterKnife.bind(this);


        LinearLayoutManager LayoutManager2 = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
        mTrailersList.setLayoutManager(LayoutManager2);
        mTrailersList.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mAdapterTrailer = new SeriesAdapter(this);
        mTrailersList.setAdapter(mAdapterTrailer);

        loadVideosData(String.valueOf(sortOrder2));

    }


    private void loadVideosData(String movieId) {
        showVideoDataView();
        new FetchVideosTask().execute(movieId);
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(SeriesItem video) {

    }


    private void showTrailerDataView() {
        mErrorMessageDisplay3.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        mTrailersList.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    private void showErrorMessage3() {
        mTrailersList.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        mErrorMessageDisplay3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    public class FetchVideosTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, ArrayList<SeriesItem>> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            mLoadingIndicatorTrailers2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        protected ArrayList<SeriesItem> doInBackground(String... params) {
            if (params.length == 0) {
                return null;
            }
            String movieId = params[0];
            URL videosRequestUrl = NetworkSeries.buildUrl(movieId);

            try {
                String jsonVideoResponse = NetworkSeries.getResponseFromHttpUrl(videosRequestUrl);

                ArrayList<SeriesItem> simpleJsonVideoData = JsonShashaDetailSeries.getSimpleMovieStringsFromJson(SeriesDetail.this, jsonVideoResponse);

                return simpleJsonVideoData;

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<SeriesItem> videoData) {
            mLoadingIndicatorTrailers2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            if (videoData != null) {
                showTrailerDataView();
                mAdapterTrailer.setMovieData(videoData);
            } else {
                showErrorMessage3();
            }
        }
    }


    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
    }

}
```

and parcalable class:

```
public class SeriesItem implements Parcelable {

    private String titles;
    private String urladaptive;

    public SeriesItem(String titles, String urladaptive) {
        this.titles = titles;
        this.urladaptive = urladaptive;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel out, int flags) {
        out.writeString(titles);
        out.writeString(urladaptive);
    }

    private SeriesItem(Parcel in) {
        this.titles         = in.readString();
        this.urladaptive         = in.readString();
    }

    public SeriesItem() {
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    public static final Creator<SeriesItem> CREATOR = new Creator<SeriesItem>() {
        @Override
        public SeriesItem createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new SeriesItem(in);
        }
        @Override
        public SeriesItem[] newArray(int i) {
            return new SeriesItem[i];
        }
    };


    public String getTitles() {
        return titles;
    }

    public StringBuilder getFullTitles() {

        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        String[] titlesArray = getTitles().split(";");
        for (String details : titlesArray) {
            builder.append(details + "\n");
        }

        return builder;
    }


    public String getUrlAdaptive() {
        return urladaptive;
    }

    public StringBuilder getFullUrlAdaptiveFinal() {

        StringBuilder builder2 = new StringBuilder();
        String[] urlArray = getUrlAdaptive().split(";");
        for (String details : urlArray) {
            builder2.append(details + "\n");
        }
        return builder2;
    }

}
```

I just try to display a toast message when onclick the above code to test the click of items and it work
but if I would like when I click on title like now so the url of same item start play
how I handle this click? in adapter itself or in activity?

Answer (score 3):

Yes this is possible. Simply use an OnClickListener and set it in your onBindViewHolder().

It would look something like this:

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.title.setText(String.valueOf(mMoviesItems.get(position).getFullTitles()));
        holder.title.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                 // Toast here
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is of course assuming that your holder.title is a TextView instance

Comment: interested answer it's work now I did what you said but can you saw the question again please in the end of it I edit it a little bit @Jacob Kaddoura

Comment: Please clarify: what exactly are you trying to do with the URL, do you want to display it in the Toast message and then go to that URL?

Also please check my answer for the help ...

Comment: the url is a link of video you can say it's youtube link so 1title1 have link and 1title2 have different link and 2title2 have different and so on I mean there is a link with each title in another key that have multiple values like the titles, so I would display the title in recycleview but when I click on any title it start to open the youtube link of this specific title 
so my question is how to handle this holder click to do this @Jacob Kaddoura

Comment: I edit the question and explain in details what I mean please read it again @Jacob Kaddoura

Comment: if you can help too please @Umang Burman read the question again because I edit it

Comment: "I just try a toast message to test the click of items and it work so if I would like when I click on title like now the url of it start play how I handle this click? in adapter itself or in activity? I'm not able to understand what exactly do you need now.

what should i do with recycleview to make this? is it something possible to do it?" @muklah this is very unclear.. please form proper sentence so we can understand.

Comment: I edit it now please read it from beginning so you can understand the situation well because I edit it from start @Umang Burman

Comment: @muklah What you are trying to achieve is not possible from the code that you have written.. You are showing all the titles in the single TextView. So you know that its title1 or title2 but android sees that its just a text on the view.. So to achieve your target you have to implement a different apprach.

Comment: For 3 titles, you have to create 3 textviews in list_item xml then you can achieve this. If you want me to post the answer for you please share your list item xml code full adapter and activity code too..

Comment: I add all classes you ask for
but it's not only 3 textviews, it's depending on the api while first id contain 3 titles and 3 urls but the second may contain 10 and so on, so I don't know hoe to deal with that I'm really stuck with it @Umang Burman

Comment: Okay, Which technology are you using to get the data from the api